# Dual boot Ubuntu 16.04/Windows 10 no longer booting

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, hard-drive, windows-10, grub-efi

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 on 2 separate hard drives (no partitions, 2 physical hard drives).

Two things have happened:

1. I no longer get the GRUB boot loader screen which allows me to choose which operating system I boot into (I recall that this used to work under a similar setting running Linux Mint 15 and Windows 7)
2. Suddenly Windows 10 won't boot anymore. Even though I set it as the first drive to boot from in the BIOS.

What am I doing wrong here?
I've seen some stuff about installing ubuntu in uefi mode. Is that something I need to consider? I am fairly new to Ubuntu and a complete noob when it comes to setting up partitions, etc.

Thank you,

BR

Johan

Comment: Did it ever worked? If so, what happened prior to Windows not booting? And if it's only Windows that isn't booting what does it have to do with Ubuntu? Yes, you need to learn about UEFI. Start here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Yes it used to work, grub bootloader did not show but if i set up the windows drive as nr 1 in bios it would boot into windows. I know this is not completely linux related but getting the grub bootloader to work, in my humble opinion is. If not then I apologize for wasting time. Thank you for the link I will check it out

Comment: If you needed that hack then you didn't have a proper dual boot because the OSes were installed in different modes, nothing to do with Grub as it can't work (for dual booting) in that situation. What's happening now is Windows related only.

Comment: Yes it turned out that I had installed Ubuntu in legacy mode :( Very well nothing to do but reinstall it then I guess. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if this question has been resolved in the comments.

> Yes it turned out that I had installed Ubuntu in legacy mode :( Very well nothing to do but reinstall it then I guess. Thanks for the help! – Johan

Comment: If on same drive with gpt partitioning, you can use Boot-Repair's advanced options to uninstall grub-pc and install grub-efi-amd64. That converts install from BIOS boot to UEFI boot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was just like CelticWarrior mentioned that my ubuntu installation was installed in Legacy mode. After reinstalling it in UEFI mode everything now works. GRUB bootloader shows up and my Windows 10 installation now boots again.